# Create JSON file with huge data

Tags: java, android, json, realm

Adding backup feature on my app and i am using Realm database, i want to backup it to a json file.
i have created the function for reading the database and create a JSONobject.
While doing the JSONobject.tostring i got a outofmemory error since i have more than 200'000 records.
any other way to create the json file.

```
RealmResults<StoneModelR> allStones = realm.where(StoneModelR.class).sort("id", Sort.ASCENDING).findAll();
for (StoneModelR singleStone : allStones) {
    try {
        JSONObject jObjectStone = new JSONObject();
        jObjectStone.put("stoneid", singleStone.id);
        jObjectStone.put("lat", singleStone.lat);
        jObjectStone.put("lng", singleStone.lon);
        jObjectStone.put("userid", singleStone.userid);
        jObjectStone.put("owner", singleStone.owner);
        jObjectStone.put("timestamp", singleStone.timestamp);
        jObjectStone.put("stonetype", singleStone.stonetype);
        jObjectStone.put("remarks", singleStone.description);
        jObjectStone.put("imported", singleStone.imported);
        jArrayStones.put(jObjectStone);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
JSONObject stoneObj = new JSONObject();
try {
    stoneObj.put("stones", jArrayStones);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What does "2lakhs" mean

Comment: You should stick to SI units in questions on SO (possibly imperial units as well).

Comment: There is no streaming support for JSON. You need a storage format that supports streaming data and not just buffering the entire data structure.

Comment: 2lakhs = 200000
Anyway with Jackson library

Comment: Realm objects are lazily loaded which is why thousands of Realm objects within a Results object has a very small memory footprint. However, as soon as those are cast to an in memory object, JSON or whatever, it looses it's lazy-loadingness. But the solution should be straight-forward. Break it down into smaller chunks, say 1000 at a time; read those in, convert to JSON, write out and release the memory. BUT - I question why go through this effort. Realm is an offline first database so why not just clone the local file? Or... write the realm data you want backed up to another Realm file?

Comment: The realm file size is around 90mb, but the json file is around 20mb and after compressed it comes under 3mb. will try to split it and give a try, Thanks

Comment: imo, building an intermediate object just to write it to JSON is just wasting of CPU/memory resources. Use streaming API https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api#writing-to-json instead. Another small tool https://github.com/anatolygudkov/green-jelly#jsongenerator